# call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I have a wordpress website and I tried to upgrade wordress version. After upgrade I got some error.

**Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WP_Duotone' not found in C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 308**

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Theme::get_block_patterns() in C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-includes\block-patterns.php:355 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(308): _register_theme_block_patterns() #1 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #2 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #3 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-settings.php(617): do_action() #4 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-config.php(98): require_once('C:\inetpub\vhos...') #5 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-load.php(50): require_once('C:\inetpub\vhos...') #6 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\inetpub\vhos...') #7 C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-admin\index.php(10): require_once('C:\inetpub\vhos...') in C:\inetpub\vhosts\gundogdukagit.com.tr\httpdocs\wp-includes\block-patterns.php on line 355**

I tried to search solutions on google but couldn't find correct one. Has anyone encountered such an error before? Can someone explain to me how to solve this problem?

I found similiar problems and articles on stackoverflow but they didn't work for my problem.

Comment: This sound like you have an incomplete update applied

Comment: However I didn't refresh the page during the update. I don't know if it solves my problem but I am thinking of downgrading it to the previous WordPress version. but I have never done this before. That's why I am not sure if I lost my website. I have backup of the database but don't have a backup of folders. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: My recommendation at this point would be to perform a manual update: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I will try